# how to fix Error with pip after 20 update

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I’m using Python 3.6.7 64x on windows 10.
Today after my updating (pip) I got this error when I’m trying to install any lib.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand, with_cleanup
ImportError: cannot import name 'with_cleanup'
```

I tried to repair the installation but it didn’t help.
So please will you tell me what I can do to fix this problem!

With all respect!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any answer for my question, and I still don't know how to solve the problem with the 20 update of pip.
but I found a way to make pip work again by using 'easy_install pip==19.3.1' in the cmd. and now i'm using the pip 19.3.1 and it works well.
hope this will help somebody!
with all respect!